# Linux file operations test program doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Could someone explain to me why does the following test program print:

abcde

fghie

jklie

m

lie

m

lie

Instead of:

abcde

fghie

jklie

mklie

mklie

The program is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char buffer[16];
void main()
{
    int fd=open("bb",O_RDONLY);
    int i;
    for(i=5;i>0;i--)
    {
        read(fd,buffer,i);
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
}
```

The file bb contains the sequence: abcdefghijklm

Comment: Your buffer is not null terminated.  Call `memset` to initialize it to all zeros before each call to `fread`.  Also might be a good idea to check the return code from `open` and `fread`.

Comment: The `read()` function does not null terminate its input. It would be a disaster if it did. You know how many bytes it read.  Don’t print more than that!

Comment: Probably the `bb` file has a newline character at the end of it which then gets read into the buffer when `i==2`.

Comment: After `read` add: `buffer[i]='\0';`

Comment: @DanielSchepler, maybe that's the point. Vi says the bb file is 14 characters long, but it should be 13 (only the letters a-m) and after the 'cat bb' command the promt appears on the next line. Obviously you are right but somehow I don't know why vi puts this '\n' character at the and automatically every time I save the file. How can I remove it?

Comment: I don't know if vi has a way to create nonempty text files without newline at the end of the last line - but you could create it manually using something like `echo -n abcdefghijklm > bb` or more interactively, `cat > bb<RET>abcdefghijklm<CTRL-d><CTRL-d>`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know that read() does not null terminate. In the exam I'm preparing for there are a lot of tricky questions related to that fact and short programs given like that one, and I should determine what the output of the program is. That's why I'm asking such stuff - I should know really good how every detail works.

Comment: You can use the `printf` command (as opposed to the function): `printf abcdefghijklm >bb`.  No newline added gratuitously and maximal portability. (More portability than `echo -n` at any rate.)

Comment: Ohhh, that's tricky (and not good programming practice in general) - I just noticed that `buffer` was declared as a global variable which would mean that it's zero-initialized.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you! 'echo -n' was all I needed. Now the file is 13 characters long and the program works as expected: it prints out exactly:abcde
fghie
jklie
mklie
mklie

Comment: The problem was that I didn't know that vi puts newline at the end and thought there's something more important that I'm doing wrong. Thank you, guys!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I will keep also the solution with printf in mind, It worked in the desired way too. I didn't know about it and the better portability. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first iteration reads "abcde", so `buffer` contains   "abcde\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" and `fd` points at 'f'
2. The second iteration reads "fghi", so `buffer` contains "fghie\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" and `fd` points at 'j'
3. The third iteration reads "jkl", so `buffer` contains "jklie\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" and `fd` points at 'm'
4. The fourth iteration reads "m\n", so `buffer` contains "m\nlie\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" and `fd` is at the end of the file
5. The fifth iteration reads nothing so nothing changes in `buffer`

Note that the code relies upon the global variable `buffer` being initialized to zero.

Comment: Does Lunix expect text files to end on a newline? I've seen compilers complain if source files don't, but I'm not sure whether this is just a convention or something more than that

Comment: Yes, that was the point. Thank you. But now I don't understand why does the '\n' pop up at the and every time I save the file and exit the vi editor? I don't press Enter nor I type \n at the end before saving.

Comment: I think the rough justification for that complaint is to consider the "grammar" for a text file to be: `TEXTFILE := LINE* ; LINE := (PRINTABLE* NONSPACE_PRINTABLE | empty) '\n'` so a nonempty file without a newline at the end is at best an incomplete text file.  (Plus, there's the practical explanation that `cat textfile` messes up shell prompt formatting if `textfile` is missing a newline at the end.)

Comment: In other words, to borrow terminology about a distinction between Pascal and C: `\n` is considered a line *terminator* not a line *separator*.